# passing several parameters through url to the same page in ASP MVC & Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, page-refresh, url-parameters

I am new to web issues and asking for advice. What I am trying to do is here:

1 - There is a Datepicker in the page with several javascript posts

2 - When the page is opened first time, the post methods should be called with initial values

3 - When I changed the date interval from Datepicker and press Submit button, the page should refresh with the new values and so the posts should be triggered again with the new values.

4 - When the page is refreshed with new values, I want the datepicker input parts (there are 2 of them) to show the updated values.

5 - **Currently, there are no initial values. Also, the 4th item on this list is missing.**

I am aware that there are a couple of basic things missing here, but I can't find out through the questions because of not knowing how the system works. Can anyone please fix my code a little?

Here is Datepicker and its JS part:

```
<li>
    <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker" style="margin-top: 10px; align-content:center">
        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="startDate" value="07/01/2015" maxlength="10" name="start" style="width:90px" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">ile</span>
        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="endDate" value="07/05/2015" maxlength="10" name="end" style="width:90px" />
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <button id="goster" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="goster()"
            style="background-color:#C71F45;color:white;
            margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px">
            Göster
    </button>
</li>

<script>
   function goster() {
        startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
        endDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value;

        var url = "http://localhost:50523/Home/Index?startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate;
        window.location.replace(url);
    }
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var QueryString = function () {
            // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
            // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
            var query_string = {};
            var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var vars = query.split("&");
            for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                // If first entry with this name
                if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
                    query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
                    // If second entry with this name
                } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
                    var arr = [query_string[pair[0]], decodeURIComponent(pair[1])];
                    query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
                    // If third or later entry with this name
                } else {
                    query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
                }
            }
            return query_string;
        }();

        $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
            format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
            autoclose: true,
            language: "tr",
            orientation: "top auto",
            todayHighlight: true
        });

        var startDate = QueryString.startDate;
        var endDate = QueryString.endDate;

        $.post(
            "/api/getUserTotalExp?startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate,
            { data: {} },
            function (data) {
                $('#totaluserexp').html(data + " saat");
            }
        );

        $.post(
             "/api/getUserExpDaily?startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate,
             { data: {} },
             function (data) {
                 ...
             }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I haven't looked into the code too much. However, you only need 1 $(document).ready() call. Combined those functions and see if you have expected behavior.

Comment: Also, this line `startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value; $('#startDate').attr("value", startDate);` does not make any sense. You can setup the default value in the datepicker options.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think, I am missing a function or something like that to get values from the url. Also, I am trying to update the value in the input field, that code was for that.

Comment: I collected all the scripts into 1 `document.ready` as you said, but still no change. How can I update `startDate` and `endDate` with the values in the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Only need a single onReady (you did that)
2. Put the code in the code and not in the markup (goster() call)
3. Since `$.post` is really an ajax shortcut, I will break that out a
   bit so we can deal with the data a bit more elegantly perhaps. (I
   used it to put the `.done` promise on the jqXHR to use (runs when
   the ajax completes with success)
4. Odd that the datepicker is not on the inputs?  Perhaps I do not know
   something but I would put them ON the inputs (how you handle that in
   reality is up to you.
5. Get the CSS/style out of the markup (leave that to you)
6. Address the issue with the post/page refresh - put that in a cookie (google that, suggest the `$.cookie` plugin perhaps?)

Markup and code:

```
<li>
    <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker" style="margin-top: 10px; align-content:center">
        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="startDate" value="07/01/2015" maxlength="10" name="start" style="width:90px" /> <span class="input-group-addon">ile</span>

        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="endDate" value="07/05/2015" maxlength="10" name="end" style="width:90px" />
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <button id="goster" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:#C71F45;color:white;
            margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px">Göster</button>
</li>
```

and code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#goster').on('click', function () {
        var startDate = $('#startDate').val();
        var endDate = $('#endDate').val();
        goster(startDate, endDate);
    });

    $('input.input-sm').datepicker({
        format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        language: "tr",
        orientation: "top auto",
        todayHighlight: true
    });

    function goster(startDate, endDate) {
        PostUserExp(startDate, endDate);
    }

    function PostUserExp(startDate, endDate) {
        //var startDate = $('#startDate').val();
        //var endDate = $('#endDate').val();
        var myajaxExp = $.ajax({
            url: "/api/getUserTotalExp",
            data: {
                "startDate": startDate,
                    "endDate": endDate
            }
        });
        myajaxExp.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // what to do with data
            $('#totaluserexp').html(data + "saat");
        });
        var myajaxDaily = $.ajax({
            url: "/api/getUserExpDaily",
            data: {
                "startDate": startDate,
                    "endDate": endDate
            }
        });
        myajaxDaily.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // what to do with data
            $('#totaluserexp').html(data + "saat");
        });
    }

    var startDate = $('#startDate').val();
    var endDate = $('#endDate').val();
    PostUserExp(startDate, endDate)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("/api/getUserExpDaily", 
  {
    'startDate': startDate,
    'endDate': endDate
  },
  function (data) {
    ....
  });
```

EDIT: data: { ... } was a typo. Oh well.

This will alway jQuery to format your dates. Now if you server is expecting JSON then it's a slightly different problem. However, the code above should work for your case.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools
The **Network** tab will allow you to inspect your post. If you looked for the line **getUserExpDaily POST**. Then you can inspect the values, format, and response from your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried this passing parameters in the data issue when I first writing the scripts. I don't know why, but the POST didn't work like it should be.

Comment: Also, I figured it out how to read parameters from the url and edited my question for remaining parts. Can you please help me about them?